# React (v18) + Typescript (v4.9) + Storybook (v7.4) + MUI not allowing stories with multiple components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, storybook

I'm recently started using storybook for my react project, In my project i'm using react + typescript + storybook + MUI, i installed storybook through this command

```
npx storybook@latest init
```

it successfully installed all the required packages and i'm able to use the stories.

So, when started using the stories with my components i was not able to use stories with multiple components, see below reference

```
// button.component.tsx

import React from 'react';
import { Button as MuiButton, ButtonProps as MuiButtonProps } from '@mui/material';
import './button.scss';


export const Button = ({ ...rest }: MuiButtonProps) => 
<div className='button'><MuiButton {...rest} /></div>;

// button.stories.ts

import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react';
import Stack from '@mui/material/Stack';
import { Button } from './Button';

const meta = {
   title: 'Example/Button',
   component: Button,
   parameters: {
    layout: 'centered',
   },
   tags: ['autodocs'],
} satisfies Meta<typeof Button>;

export default meta;
type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>;

export const Variants: Story = {
    render: (args) => <Stack spacing={2}>
         <Button {...args} variant='container'> Contained Button </Button>
         <Button {...args} variant='outlined'> Outlined Button </Button>
         <Button {...args} Text Button </Button>
    </Stack>
}
```

started getting this issue

```
'Stack' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Stack'?
```

please kindly help me solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you can solve this.

1. Add the Stack to the decorators instead of in your story

   ```
   const meta: Meta<typeof Button> = {
   title: "Example/Button",
   component: Button,
   parameters: {
       layout: "centered",
   },
   tags: ["autodocs"],
   decorators: [
       (Story) => {
           return (
               <Stack spacing={2}>
                   <Story />
               </Stack>
           );
       },
   ],
   ```

   };

Then in your story

```
export const Variants: Story = {
    render: (args) => (
      <>
         <Button {...args} variant='container'> Contained Button </Button>
         <Button {...args} variant='outlined'> Outlined Button </Button>
         <Button {...args} Text Button </Button>
      </>
    )
}
```

1. The other method is to just create the function without making it a story type. As long as it is exported it will display:

export const Variants = (args) => {

```
<Stack spacing={2}>
     <Button {...args} variant='container'> Contained Button </Button>
     <Button {...args} variant='outlined'> Outlined Button </Button>
     <Button {...args} Text Button </Button>
</Stack>
```

}